# Handeling adapters from list view to single item view class

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I have a class viewroom.java, to list all the rooms' title from database, as follows:

```
    package com.iwantnew.www;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    //import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    public class viewroom extends ListActivity {

        // url to make request
        private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/iWant/src/android_view_all_room.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_ROOM = "room";
       // private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
        private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
        private static final String TAG_QUANTITY = "quantity";
        private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
        private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contact";
        private static final String TAG_AREA = "area";
        private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
        private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray room = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_room);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            // Hashmap for ListView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> roomList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                room = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ROOM);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < room.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = room.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String quantity = c.getString(TAG_QUANTITY);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String contact = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT);
                    String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_QUANTITY, quantity);
                    map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    map.put(TAG_CONTACT, contact);
                    map.put(TAG_AREA, area);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    roomList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, roomList,
                    R.layout.list_room,
                    new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_LOCATION, TAG_PRICE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.title, R.id.location, R.id.price });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();
            // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                    String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location)).getText().toString();
                    String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();            
                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleRoomActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

when one of those list item is clicked, details are shown in single Room Activity class. it 
is as follows:

```
package com.iwantnew.www;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleRoomActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_room);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String title = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TITLE);
        String location = in.getStringExtra(TAG_LOCATION);
        String price = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PRICE);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_label);
        TextView lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_label);
        TextView lblPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_label);

        lblTitle.setText(title);
        lblLocation.setText(location);
        lblPrice.setText(price);
    }

}
```

there remains a big gap between each items in view room activity class, when all details are shown in single room activity.

and when list adapter is modified to

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, roomList,
                R.layout.list_room,
                new String[] { TAG_TITLE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title });
```

in view room activity, the gap vanishes but, single room activity does not show all the description.

in case you need my xml files:
view_room.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slogan"
        android:text="@string/Search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slogan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchArea"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brand"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/iWant"
        android:textSize="@dimen/iwant" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/postBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:text="@string/post" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/room_list_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:text="@string/room_list_heading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="normal" />

        <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/room_list_heading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

single room.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <!-- Name Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/title_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"/>
  <!-- Description Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/quantity_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/location_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/price_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/contact_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/description_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/area_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/address_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_room.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  
        <!-- Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
        <!-- Description label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: this is view room's snap shot]

[image: This is single room's snap shot]

I want to vanish gap in the first picture and still get the second picture as it is.

Comment: what is the question and the problem your facing?

Comment: you should use activity context `Intent in = new Intent(viewroom.this, SingleRoomActivity.class)`

Comment: how do I vanish the gap in viewrooms' list and still get the details in single room? till now, when I do one, I am unable to do other.

Comment: you should post a screen shot of how it looks.

Comment: @Raghunandan I got my screenshots uploaded, please review.

Comment: i think you need to override getView() method and need to check TAG_TITLE, TAG_LOCATION, TAG_PRICE are empty or not from every map and if they empty then GONE the visibility of particular TextView.